# How does the code for each API exposed via AZURE API Gateway Stored?

Tags: azure-api-management

I am new to Azure API Manager, I have used Apigee Edge before where you can store each api proxy code in either git or SVN. But in Azure I am not sure how each API that is exposed via the gateway is stored. I can see there is a repository for the whole API Manager instance. Does that mean all the APIs are bundled to the same Gateway Instance and stored there?

I am planning to build a CI/CD pipeline to create the APIs in the API Manager for that I need to understand how the APIs code will be stored.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the GIT repository for the apimanagement instance, you can fetch it in form of ARM templates. Refer this blog.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/build-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-api-management/

Comment: Greetings JJ, Thanks for that. that helps. I will check that.

Comment: Greetings @Vitaliy, thanks for that. Yes I have referred to that. we have few limitations using this approach. The ARM approach does not handle.

   Name Value Pairs
   Environment specific policy files
   API revisions for rollback
   APIs with no swagger file, ie. blank and function backed APIs
But these can be addressed using the powershell commands. My question is is the powershell commands approach is better over the ARM templates?

Comment: Here is our requirement, 1. The API Proxies will have common policies that will be applied whenever a new API is created.
2. The API Proxies should be able to promote to the next SDLC environment without manually needing to develop them again in the next SDLC environment.
3. The Developers should have a provision to create any custom policies other than the common ones and be able to promote them to the next SDLC.
4. The deployment and backout of the API Proxies needs to be automated so its visible to the product owners.
5. Blank and Azure Functions should be supported.